# MySql Query with Select Count and Group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm developing a php page and I should make a MySql query for extract some data from a table.

My table is like this:

Date (datetime) | Code (text)

```
2016-02-25 11:47:01 | FOO
2016-02-25 17:25:03 | BAR
2016-02-24 10:42:04 | BAR
2016-02-24 19:45:05 | BAR
2016-01-17 13:12:06 | BAR
2016-02-23 22:36:07 | XXX
2016-02-20 03:25:08 | YYY
```

I would like to write a query to obtain only "BAR" with count of occurrency by day, something like:

```
2016-02-25 | 1
2016-02-24 | 2
2016-01-17 | 1
```

The only part of query that I'm able to write is SELECT [...] WHERE Code="BAR" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will work for you

```
    select DATE(`datetime`)as date,count(Date)
    from table_name
WHERE Code = 'BAR'
    group by DATE(`datetime`)
```

Comment: You need to trim off the time part to get grouping by date.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `GROUP BY` the *date* part of the `datetime` field:

```
SELECT DATE(`datetime`), COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
WHERE Code = 'BAR'
GROUP BY DATE(`datetime`)
```